Screen blank but Services Running
I've got a Windows 11 Pro system running at a remote location that I use with Teamviewer.
This recent time, the system was up for 4 days and then all of the sudden I couldn't use Teamviewer with it. The screen was black and no cursor.
I went to the local keyboard/mouse/monitor and tried them. Nothing on the screen as well except the top left.
All of the local services such as Blue Iris (CCTV), Network pings work, etc. The system is still very much on and working but no video. It's unpredictable when it happens and the only way to recover is to restart the system.
This recent time was just 2 hours and the screen is black with no response

Thanks for the comments on this.
I can do a remote restart with Teamviewer.
The system is close enough that I can go to it, I just designed it's placement so that I didnt have to be in that room often
I still have no idea why the system stays up for 2-3 days (or 4 hours) and then just stops showing any desktop, icons,  or even cursor movement, yet it is still very much alive and processing the CCTV

Anyone have a suggestion? The local screen is just blank, no mouse cursor and keyboard attempts dont' work.

Removed teamviewer.  No more hangs.  Tried NoMachine

Removed Teamviewer and tested with similar software.  No more issues.   Seems it was something to do with how teamviewer hooked the display driver.
